# Substracting two registers in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a problem: need to substract a value from register. How do I know if the result is negative or positive?

```
localparam num_of_clocks = 10000000; 

reg [23:0] DELAY;
reg [23:0] COUNTER;

DELAY = COUNTER - num_of_clocks;
```

I need to display the decimal value of DELAY with its sign. What is the right way to do it? Nothing that I've tried seems to work.

Comment: Keep datatyps `signed` and then you can simple add the 2 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How about making your variables `signed`?

```
localparam num_of_clocks = 10000000;

reg signed [23:0] DELAY;
reg signed [23:0] COUNTER;

DELAY = COUNTER - num_of_clocks;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3xLp